# What keyword to use to change directory in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

this is just really a very basic robot test case/script. This is exporting .csv file from web.

```
 *** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library  OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${DIR}            C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Reports

*** Test Cases ***
Sample exporting of csv file

    empty directory  ${DIR}
    ${prefs} =    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${DIR}
    open browser  https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com  headlesschrome  executable_path=${BROWSERDRI}  options=add_experimental_option("prefs",${prefs})
    input text  //*[@id="name"]  xxxxx
    input password  //*[@id="password"]  xxxxx
    click button  //*[@id="button_primary"]
    click element  //*[@id="content-header"]/div/span[3]/a/div
    click element  //*[@id="exportDropdown"]/ul/li[3]/a
    click link  //*[@id="exportCsvColumns_control"]/div/div[1]/div/a[2]
    click button  //*[@id="exportSubmit"]
    sleep  5s
    move file  oldfilename  newfilename
    close browser
```

As you can see the file will be downloaded in C:\Users\xxxxx\Reports. Now, I want to rename the file. So I just put "move file  oldfilename   newfilename" and the error is:

C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\ExportFiles\oldfilename' does not exist.

And that is where my .robot file is located. How can I go back to C:\Users\xxxxx\Reports so that I can change the filename using 'move file'? Or if you have a better suggestion? Goal is just to change the filename of the downloaded file. Please bear with me as I am just practicing Robot. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it is telling you the file doesn't exist, it doesn't exist. Please post the actual error. The error you posted either isn't the full error, or it's telling you that your filename ends with a single quote.

Comment: Hi Bryan, yes, it is not existing in C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\ExportFiles\oldfilename because it is indeed in C:\Users\xxxxx\Reports. That is why I am asking how can I go back to C:\Users\xxxxx\Reports so that I can perform the "move file  oldfilename  newfilename"

Comment: Why not just give it the correct path? There's no need to change the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the full name of the file to the keyword - if you don't, it defaults to the current working dir of the parent process, which happens to be the suite's/the robot binary:

```
Move File  ${DIR}\\oldfilename    ${DIR}\\newfilename
```

Comment: Thank you Todor, it worked.